# IOS NSURLConnection and AFImageRequestOperation strange behavior

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, afnetworking

I'm absolutely a noob and I really need your help. I'm searching for a solution for already one week, but i really don't know how to do.
I'm trying to download some icons (png images) from a web service, and I've already used the code somewhere else, but just for 1 image, not for multiples images.
In this case I should download 15 images.
In both case, using AFImageRequestOperation or NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest, i reach the end for all the 15 images but after that it start with an error that i really don't know how to fix because it shouldn't appear there! (*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray CGPointValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance).
If I download the 15 images with a synchronousRequest no problems at all.
What I'm doing wrong? Is it my mistake here or somewhere else?
Many thanks.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imagePath]];
AFImageRequestOperation *operation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:request imageProcessing``Block:nil                                                                                            success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
         // Save Image
        [images_icon addObject:image ];
        if ([images_icon count]==[allIcons count]) {
            [self saveAllImagesToDisk];
        }
        }
        failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
          NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
          UIAlertView* allerta=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Attention"
                    message:@"Some problems here.."
                    delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
          [allerta show];
        }];
    [operation start];
```

---

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:percorsoImmagine];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]; 
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {NSLog(@"lungh %d, error=%@ mime=%@",[data length], error, response.MIMEType);
         if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil && ([response.MIMEType isEqualToString:@"image/png"] || [response.MIMEType isEqualToString:@"image/jpeg"])){
             [images_icon addObject:data ];
             if ([images_icon count]==[allIcons count]) {
                [self saveAllImagesToDisk];
             }
         }
     }];
```

Comment: Show us exactly where it crashes. Set a breakpoint in each case and step in the debugger until it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `AFImageRequestOperation` you are adding `UIImage`s to `images_icon` but when you use `NSURLConnection` you are adding `NSData`s to `images_icon`. We would need to see `[self saveAllImagesToDisk]` to investigate further.

Comment: Thank You Ric. I was trying something different there; the method is empty, I excluded each single line inside saveAllImagesToDisk, but I'm getting the same error, before entering it. Sometimes it stop on the last image, other on random position. I was thinking to some internet speed problem :(

Comment: there was no problem at all with the code. For some reason, some  images were causing the problem. I delete them on server, i re-created the wrong ones, and now everything is working as it should.. Thanks!